# Setting up subdomain using google domains

Tags: dns, subdomain

I have a domain that I bought on Google Domains, and have a website hosted on it using Hugo + Netlify. I'd like to use a separately hosted blog website based on Jekyll on a subdomain with the name `blog.example.com`.

Looking online I was able to find - https://support.google.com/domains/answer/6072198?hl=en, which it seems like will re-direct the subdomain to a different web address, but not exactly allow me to host my site on that subdomain.

Can anyone explain to me how I can go about doing that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need a `CNAME` record in your Google DNS:
`blog.example.com` will point to `192.0.2.4` (use the IP given to you)
Then the subdomain `blog` will be in the hands of your blog hosting provider.

If there is a `CNAME` record for `*.example.com`, you will need to replace that by `www.example.com` to point towards your `example.com` A record (which points to your default website host's IP)

Comment: I think you meant that the blog.example.com will have A record pointing to IP, eg.:
`blog.example.com A 3600 192.0.2.4` <- (use the IP given to you)